# What alternative sql method can I use to see more records, GROUP BY id only shows one row per unique id

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, query, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

What I want is per map id I want to be able to see the top highest scoring gangs (also I should be able to say from which date or a specific single day), (i thought of using GROUP BY ID, but it would only return one record per map id). How could I achieve this? or is not possible with how the table is setup?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49ade2/1

Comment: I've tagged your question as MySQL 5.6 because you have used this version in your fiddle. Please change it if that is not your actual MySQL version.

Comment: If you said you want per map id, why would you grouping it by `ID`?

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 5.6 you can use a subquery to get the date:

```
select 
    t2.map_id,
    max(t2.score),
    (select t1.date
     from    test t1
     where   t1.map_id = t2.map_id
             and t1.score = max(t2.score)) as date
from 
    test t2
group by
    t2.map_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49ade2/20)